# WebDAV or CIFS with Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, webdav, mdm, cifs

I'm trying to create an add-on for an MDM that can integrate with a data repository, specifically Google Drive, via WebDAV or CIFS (only protocols supported for the MDM). The MDM creates a "safe" container on a mobile device, tablet or phone, that prevents certain actions on files via policies. Both WebDAV and CIFS have a file locking mechanism which would work well with Sharepoint (check in/out), but goes against the real-time collaboration that Google Drive offers (native Gdocs only). I haven't found much on using these protocols with Google Drive and was wondering why hasn't a solution been created already. Basically, I'm trying to figure out if its worth starting the project or am I going to run into roadblocks that limit or prevent functionality.

Comment: What platform are you talking about (iOS, Windows, Android)?